# jquery.post() and backend responded, but parameter of the callback function is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, http, web.py

Linux bogon 3.9.5-301.fc19.i686,nginx1.4.2 + web.py0.37 + uwsgi2.01

I writed a html page which gets a user's input(a text string), and post it to backend.The backend just read the input string and send back to the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#ExtButton").click(function(){
        var postdata = document.getElementById("url_to_get").value;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/TextPickup",
            data: postdata,
            success: function(data,status){alert("status:"+ status +",data:" +data)},
            dataType:'html'
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
<input type="text" name="url_to_get" id="url_to_get" style="width:310px">
<button id="ExtButton">send</button>
```

and the python script in backend:

```
import web
import os
urls = (
'/','Index',
'/TextPickup','TextPickup',
'/TextAnalysis', 'TextAnalysis'
)

class Index:
    ...

class TextPickup:
    def POST(self):
        dest_url = web.data()
        return dest_url + ".."

class TextAnalysis:
    ...
```

but when I put something and click the button,the data is empty like below:
[image]

I have checked the output of uWSGI,

```
[pid: 20807|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {50 vars in 800 bytes} [Sun Feb 23 13:44:58 2014] POST /TextPickup => generated 6 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 0 headers in 19 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

and even the wireshark:
[image]
It's clear that the backend have send response successfully including the string "test.." I expected,but **why the callback function didn't get the response string as its parameter?**

**UPDATE:**
in firebug,
[image]
when I right-clicked the `http://127.0.0.1/TextPickup` and selected "Open in New Tab",
a page including the expected string "test.." appeared.however, it is supposed to be the parameter of the callback function.

Comment: can you inspect the response using the browser developer tool's network tab

Comment: Since you are sending plain text, can you try with dataType : 'text'

Comment: it looks like your python script is returning it in hexadecimal form, otherwise in your 'wireshark' response area it would have your response in string form. Try explicitly casting your `dest_url` var as a string (sorry if this is wrong, I've never used python before so this is just a guess)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have tried firebug to check the response,but can't figure out still

Comment: @palanik both 'text' and 'html' don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why it didn't work -- **the web.py is not used correctly,and the browse to the web page is also wrong**.

first, I arranged the file like below:

```
folder1
--GetText.html
--cgi-bin
    --TextAnalysis.py
```

and accessed the web page by just clicking the file GetText.html.
the error happended.

I reviewed some pages about web.py and jQuery,such as [random Bytes](http://sreeharikmarar.blogspot.com/2011/10/ajax-webpy-how-to-load-data-from-server.html), even a forum's source code used web.py and jQuery on github, realized the `/template` folder is not unnecessary.

Now I rearrange the files like this

```
folder1
--TextAnalysis.py
--templates
    --GetText.html
```

thus jquery.post() in `GetText.html` is changed to

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/TextPickup",
    data: postdata,
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    dataType:'text'
});
```

in `TextAnalysis.py`:

```
class Index:
    def GET(self):
    return render.GetText()

...

render = web.template.render('templates/') #add up
```

now I visist the web page by typing url `http://127.0.0.1/` in firefox, and all works fine.